# Node.js net.connect errors to friendly messages

Tags: node.js

The error object I get on a net.connect failure looks like:

```
{"code":"ETIMEDOUT","errno":"ETIMEDOUT","syscall":"connect"}
```

Is there a module to translate those into user-readable messages? e.g. "Connection timed out". I was unable to find anything.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those codes are POSIX error codes used in linux. Their description is given in errno.h file. See [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) and [here](http://www.virtsync.com/c-error-codes-include-errno). You can create an error object yourself or you can use [errno](https://npmjs.org/package/errno) package.